# How do I read JSON using pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas

How do I read the json below in pandas:

```
[
    {
        "DataVal": {
            "sales": "0.00000",
            "cost": "926.00000",
            "os": "And",
            "hr": "0",
            "_id": "34358",
            "month": "10",
            "date": "2021-10-11"
        }
    },
    {
        "DataVal": {
            "sales": "0.00000",
            "cost": "830.00000",
            "os": "And",
            "hr": "0",
            "_id": "24158",
            "month": "10",
            "date": "2021-01-02"
        }
    },
    {
        "DataVal": {
            "sales": "0.00000",
            "cost": "128.00000",
            "os": "And",
            "hr": "0",
            "_id": "23358",
            "month": "10",
            "date": "2021-10-03"
        }
    }
```

Current Output

| DataVal |
| --- |
| {'sales': '0.00000', 'cost': '96.00000', 'os': 'And', 'hr': '0', '_id': '24358', 'month': '10', 'date': '2021-10-01'} |
| {'sales': '0.00000', 'cost': '96.00000', 'os': 'And', 'hr': '0', '_id': '24358', 'month': '10', 'date': '2021-10-01'} |

Expected Output:

| Sales | Cost | os |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.000 | 234 | And |

Above table with other additional columns like os,hr, _id, month

Comment: looks like the json you've posted is cut off - can you post the code you used as well please?

Comment: Currently, I am just using df= pd.read_json('FileName'), there might be a parameter  that could solve the problem. 
Additionally, the json file just contains several blocks of DataVal till EOF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read JSON file into `data` using `json`

```
import json 

with open('path/to/json.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Or if it's from an API call (using `requests`)

```
data = response.json()
```

Then you just need

```
df = pd.DataFrame(rec['DataVal'] for rec in data)
```

Output:

```
>>> df 

     sales       cost   os hr    _id month        date
0  0.00000  926.00000  And  0  34358    10  2021-10-11
1  0.00000  830.00000  And  0  24158    10  2021-01-02
2  0.00000  128.00000  And  0  23358    10  2021-10-03
```

Setup:

```
data = [
    {
        "DataVal": {
            "sales": "0.00000",
            "cost": "926.00000",
            "os": "And",
            "hr": "0",
            "_id": "34358",
            "month": "10",
            "date": "2021-10-11"
        }
    },
    {
        "DataVal": {
            "sales": "0.00000",
            "cost": "830.00000",
            "os": "And",
            "hr": "0",
            "_id": "24158",
            "month": "10",
            "date": "2021-01-02"
        }
    },
    {
        "DataVal": {
            "sales": "0.00000",
            "cost": "128.00000",
            "os": "And",
            "hr": "0",
            "_id": "23358",
            "month": "10",
            "date": "2021-10-03"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: I am getting a TypeError
df = pd.DataFrame(rec['DataVal'] for rec in data)
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: `x1=json.dumps(x,indent=4)`
`data= pd.read_json(x1)`
`df = pd.DataFrame(rec['DataVal'] for rec in data)`
`print(df)`

Comment: @Aakash That is not what I meant, I've updated the answer, see if it works now.

Comment: So, I am running an api call, once I get the output in using .json(), there is no way to directly read that as a dataframe? I first need to write the response into a file, in your code "data.json" then read it. 
If I write the api reponse into a json and follow the steps above it works.

Comment: @Aakash I assumed that you were reading the JSON from a file. Those types of details should be clear in the description to avoid misunderstandings and assumptions. In that case `data` is just the output of `response.json()`, no need to write it to a file and read it.

Comment: Apologies, will add better description next time.
This works, Thanks!

Comment: @Aakash No worries! You're welcome, I'm glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try json_normalize

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open('path_to_json.json') as f:
  data = json.load(f)
  df = json_normalize(data)
  df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('DataVal.', '')

Result
      sales       cost   os hr    _id month        date
0  0.00000  926.00000  And  0  34358    10  2021-10-11
1  0.00000  830.00000  And  0  24158    10  2021-01-02
2  0.00000  128.00000  And  0  23358    10  2021-10-03
```